# Google Analytics API: hour of event vs hour of session?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Suppose I have the following queries:

```
d1 = service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:xxxxxxx',
      start_date='2016-04-25',
      end_date='2016-05-14',
      metrics='ga:users',
      dimensions='ga:dimension1,ga:hour,ga:date',
      sort='-ga:date',
      start_index='1',
      max_results='1500').execute()

d2 = service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:xxxxxxx',
      start_date='2016-04-25',
      end_date='2016-05-14',
      metrics='ga:uniqueEvents',
      dimensions='ga:dimension1,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:date,ga:hour',
      sort='-ga:date',
      start_index='1',
      max_results='1500').execute()
```

`ga:dimension1` is being populated with a user-scoped client ID unique to each user.

The goal is to join `d1` and `d2` on `ga:date`,`ga:hour`, and `ga:dimension1`.

But suppose a user begins a session at hour 10, and triggers an event at hour 12. `d1` would give hour = 10, but would `d2` give hour = 10 or 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event will get the hour when the event happened, i.e. `d2` will give hour=12 in your example.

My way to go around this is to add the dimension `ga:sessionDurationBucket` in the query, which gives, in seconds, the duration of the session (see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessiondurationbucket)). I'm not sure what language do you use to access the api, anyway I won't post code but just the steps to solve the problem. (I use `R` and of course I can post my code if you think it helps).

- I construct a timestamp for each record from `ga:date`, `ga:hour` and `ga:minute`
- I group the records by `ga:dimension1` and `ga:sessionDurationBucket`
- For each of the groups, in a loop: (a) I get the older timestamp, and add the session duration (`ga:sessionDurationBucket`/60+1)/(60*24) to get the "last" timestamp, (b) I assign to the session all records from the first timestamp to the last timestamp of the session, and (c) if there are records remaining, the new first timestamp is the older timestamp of these remaining records, and I go to (a)
- After the loop, "all" registers are assigned to a session and I do the processing (I put all between quotes because there may be a few registers in the process that I cannot assign, but usually a negligible number)

I hope it is clear enough and it helps. If you think it's useful, I can post `R` code, or maybe if you tell me which programming language you use and I can try and rewrite it...

---

*ADDED after comments*: sample code in R

I'm using `RGoogleAnalytics` library, this is the query I run (note in this case I don't use `dimension1` since the website I'm working with does not have it set):

```
query.coll.d <- Init(start.date=start_date.d,
                     end.date=end_date.d,
                     dimensions=c("ga:date",
                                  "ga:hour",
                                  "ga:minute",
                                  "ga:sourceMedium",
                                  "ga:pagePath",
                                  "ga:previousPagePath",
                                  "ga:sessionDurationBucket"),
                     metrics=c("ga:sessions",
                               "ga:pageviews",
                               "ga:newUsers"),
                     table.id="ga:XXX view id XXX",
                     sort="-ga:date,-ga:hour,-ga:minute",
                     max.results = 20000)

ga.query.d <- QueryBuilder(query.coll.d)
ga.data.coll.d <- GetReportData(ga.query.d, token, paginate_query=TRUE)
```

From that, I build the timestamp (note that GA does not provide seconds),

```
require(chron)
ga.data.coll.d$datetime <- chron(ga.data.coll.d$date, paste(ga.data.coll.d$hour,
                                                            ga.data.coll.d$minute,
                                                            '00',
                                                            sep=":"),
                                 format=c("ymd","h:m:s"))
```

This is a function to create a unique userId, using a global variable, so that I can use it later inside my function.

```
userId <- 1
getNewId <- function() {
  current <- get("userId", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  current <- current + 1
  assign("userId", current, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return(current)
}
```

This is the function in which I process the results of the group by according to the algorithm I tried to describe above, where `sessionDurationBucket` is an integer, and `datetimes` and `sessions` are the lists of sessions and timestamps of the group by.

```
one_minute <- 1/(60*24)
setUserId <- function(datetimes, sessions, sessionDurationBucket) {
  if (length(datetimes) == 1) {
    # just one row received
    return(getNewId())
  }
  if (sum(sessions) == 1) {
    # just one session, all rows belong to the same user
    return(getNewId())
  }
  users <- rep(NA, length(datetimes))
  if (sessionDurationBucket == 0) {
    # sessions of 1 page and length 0 => assign a user per session
    for (i in 1:length(datetimes)) {
      users[i] <- getNewId()
    }
    return(users)
  }
  # general case
  minutes <- ceiling(as.numeric(sessionDurationBucket)/60) + 1
  i <- 1
  while(TRUE) {
    index_lag <- (datetimes >= datetimes[i] - minutes*one_minute) & is.na(users)
    sessions_lag <- sum(sessions[index_lag])
    if (sessions_lag == 1) {
      users[index_lag] <- getNewId()
    } else {
      # two or more sessions mixed together
      users[index_lag] <- 0
    }
    # look for remaining users (without id yet)
    rem_users <- which(is.na(users))
    if (length(rem_users) == 0) {
      break
    }
    i <- min(rem_users)
  }
  return(users)
}
```

And I use `data.table` for the running the group by and creating the new column (note that in your case you could use `dimension1` instead of `sourceMedium` in the group by). Also note, it assumes the registers are ordered inversely by date, which is done in the GA query.

```
require(data.table)
ga.data.coll.dt <- data.table(ga.data.coll.d)
ga.data.coll.dt[, userId:=setUserId(datetime, sessions, sessionDurationBucket), by=list(sessionDurationBucket, sourceMedium)]
```

Finally I remove all the registers that have `userId` equal to 0, since for those the code above could not resolve the session. In my case, a negligible number.

I actually plan to write a post in my humble blog, including some more explanations, but I won't be able to do it until the end of the month... Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Irnzcig, `ga:sessionDurationBucket` looks like the way to go. I'm using Python, but I am most fluent in R, so any R code would greatly help so I can really wrap my head around your method.

Comment: Updated. Hope it is useful!